# Prestashop Fedex integration error

Tags: prestashop, fedex

I am integrating fedex module in Prestashop. I entered my-

1. fedex account number.
2. fedwx meter number.
3. developer test key.
4. fedex password

When i hit save buotton , i am facing this error -

Prestashop could not connect to Fedex webservices :
Error 1000 : Authentication Failed
 Connect to Fedex Module Status
Connect to Fedex is not configured yet. You must:

1) Complete the "General Settings" form

2) Select your available delivery service

3) Webservice test connection : Error 1000 : Authentication Failed

4) Soap is enabled

5) Url fopen is enabled

6) OpenSSL is enabled

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your email for one from FedEx. It contains a production password which is different from your myFedEx password. This is the one you'll enter into the password field.